# Motivations of the the First Crusade

Tags: europe, catholic-church, crusades

What sort of balance in motivation existed for the first Crusade between answering a plea for assistance from the Byzantine Empire and reclamation of Jerusalem?

Obviously it would vary between individuals at the time of the Crusade's inception.  I want to get an overview of the presumably different sort of motivations that existed for people in various positions.

Any answers from personal accounts(such as Pope Urban II,  Godfrey of Bouillon or common people/Crusaders) or a from governing bodies(the Church) is what I'm looking for.

---

I read the question and answers on the other topic, it did not touch on the feelings of common people or Crusaders. While it answers part of the question, I was hoping for some examples of people in more varied positions of power and influence.

Comment: I was hoping to see evidence indicative of motives, pertaining to the largely unaffiliated and to those instrumental to in putting the Crusade into motion.

Comment: See http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/7915/are-there-any-historians-who-believe-that-the-crusades-were-not-motivated-as-a-d/7918#7918 for an extended discussion

Comment: +1 and welcome. I voted to close, though, because it's essentially  a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: Helping Constantinople was certainly NOT among the main motivations.